# Have extra while loop conditions ... based on a condition?

Tags: python, while-loop

The variable `a` can take any number of values. The value of `a` is the amount of extra pre-defined conditions to have for the while loop.

This can be done with multiple `elif` statements but is there a cleaner way of doing this?

```
if a == 0:
    while condition_1:
        ...
elif a == 1:
    while condition_1 or condition_2:
        ...
elif a == 2:
    while condition_1 or condition_2 or condition_3:
        ...
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Could you give us a more specific example please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A general way of doing what other languages do with a `switch` statement is to create a dictionary containing a function for each of your cases:

```
conds = {
    0: lambda: condition_1,
    1: lambda: condition_1 or condition_2,
    2: lambda: condition_1 or condition_2 or condition_3
}
```

Then:

```
while conds[a]():
    # do stuff
```

By using lambdas (or named functions if your conditions are particularly complex) the appropriate condition can be evaluated each time through the loop, instead of once when the dictionary is defined.

In this simple case where your `a` has sequential integer values starting at 0, you could use a list and save a bit of typing. To further simplify, you could define each of your conditions in terms of the previous one, since you're just adding a condition each time:

```
conds = [
     lambda: condition_1,
     lambda: conds[0]() or condition_2,
     lambda: conds[1]() or condition_3
]
```

Or, as suggested by Julien in a comment:

```
conds = [
     lambda: condition_1,
     lambda: condition_2,
     lambda: condition_3
]

while any(cond() for cond in conds[:a+1]):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: +1 on a clever and simplistic solution. However, You may want to specify on why lambdas - if I interpret correctly, it's because not using them would cause the boolean values to be fixed at dictionary initialization, correct?

Comment: Yes. You could also use named functions for particularly complex conditions. In any case it needs to be a function to defer evaluation until later (and to allow repeated evaluation).

Comment: I personally would recommend putting that into the answer directly, so if someone who doesn't understand comes in they would have an immediate explanation

Comment: That list idea is incredibly clever. I might have to go see if you have any other gems in your answers on the site, heh.

Comment: small improvement (maybe?): define `conds = [lambda: cond1, lambda: cond2, ...]` and then `while any([cond() for cond in conds[:a]])`

Comment: argh, @Julien got there before me, I wanted to suggest that, but wasn't on a computer. One minor change though: you don't need a list inside the any, it can just be a generator (this way the entire list doesn't need to get created).

Comment: That's a great one, @JulienBernu.

Comment: @kindall Brilliant answer, thank you. Could you possibly explain why the parentheses are needed here `while conds[a]()` because I missed that originally and it led to a lot of head scratching.

Comment: The parentheses are needed because `conds[a]` is a function and it must be called in order to evaluate the condition(s) defined in it. Somewhat confusingly, function objects are "truthy" by themselves, so if you don't call the function, your `while` loop runs forever.

Comment: @kindall Hello, you mentioned using a `switch` in other languages and so I tried it in Java using `switch` and `case` but the only way I could make it work is by putting a `while` loop in each `case`. Could you perhaps tell me what functions I should be using to achieve this in Java? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like this:

```
while (a >= 0 and condition_1) or (a >= 1 and condition_2) or (a >= 2 and condition_3) ...
```

Comment: While technically correct I'd like to advise readers that this is a somewhat wordy, excessive and non-Pythonic solution, especially if the conditionals get increasingly complex.

Comment: While a little less elegant, your answer worked right off the bat for me. Could you explain for me, how it's working? is the `(a >= 0 and condition_1)` a mini-if statement?

Comment: The `and` keyword is logically equivalent to nested `if` statements, so, sorta...

Answer (score 2):

You could define a function to be evaluated for `while`:

```
def test(a):
    if a == 1:
        return condition1(...)
    elif a == 2:
        return condition2(...) or condition1(...)
    elif a == 3:
        return condition2(...) or condition1(...) or condition3(...)
    else:
        return False

# test(a) will check the conditions ... define additional arguments if you need them
while test(a):
    do_stuff
```

It does have still the elifs but you don't need to write the `while`-loop multiple times.